# How to trap the insert smartart dialog in powerpoint

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I know how to add smart art to the slide, but it always fills the slide. My customer wants to place the smart art automatically in certain places on the slide. I can't see how to trap the insert smartart dialog to get the smartart and place it myself on the slide. Does anyone have nay suggestions on how I might accomplish this? BTW, How to I find the mso code that I can put on my ribbon to invoke the insert smartart dialog?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add an event handler, then trap the selection change event.  When the selection changes, determine whether the current selection is a smart art shape. If so, look at the smart art shape's .Tags collection to see if it's been tagged.  If so, leave it alone.  If not, tag it and resize it.

Try SmartArtInsert (generally you can figure out the names if you go into PPT's Customize Ribbon dialog and hover the mouse pointer over the control you're interested in)

Comment: I don't see a selection change event. The SlideSelectionChanged event does not fire when I insert new SmartArt.

Comment: OK. I found that the WindowSelectionChnage event fires when I insert smart art.

Comment: Yes, because PPT leaves the SmartArt selected after insertion. SelectionChange fires whenever ANYTHING is selected (or unselected) so you'll need to look at the selection .Count and .Type and if the type indicates that shapes are selected, then make sure that the type of .Selection.ShapeRange(1) is smartart (I don't remember the name/value of the constant at the moment but intellisense will tell you.